# MVC 2 on IIS 7.5 getting 404 error when trying to load partial views with jquery using relative path - works with full path

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a new MVC 2 site that has been working fine on my local box but has a path issue when published to an IIS 7.5 server.  The site pulls up fine, navigation links such as

```
<ul id="menu">              
      <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
      <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", "Search")%></li>
      <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Help", "About", "Home")%></li>
```

work just fine.  However, when trying to load a partial view with jQuery via code like this

```
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search Alumni Directory" onclick='loadSearchResults( )' />
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadSearchResults(val) {

        var formData = $("#search-form").serializeArray(); // muy importante

        $('div.search-results').load('/Search/LoadResults/', formData, function () {
            $('div.search-results-pending').show().delay(1000).hide(500);
            $('div.search-instructions').hide();
            $('div.search-results').show('slow');
         });

    }

</script>
```

I get a 404 error because the path is

```
http://test-alumni.indiana.edu/Search/LoadResults
```

instead of

```
http://test-alumni.indiana.edu/OnlineDirectory/Search/LoadResults
```

adding '/OnlineDirectory' to the path in my load function solves the problem but it does not seem like I should have to do this.  I am publishing to a directory that is configured as an application.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the browser is resolving the "/" path based on the hostname, test-alumni.indiana.edu.  If your page is relative to /OnlineDirectory, try it without the "/" in front of "Search".

Comment: Thanks Derrick for the simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadSearchResults(val) {

    var formData = $("#search-form").serializeArray(); // muy importante
    var url = '<%: Url.Action("LoadResults,"Search")%>';
    $('div.search-results').load(url, formData, function () {
        $('div.search-results-pending').show().delay(1000).hide(500);
        $('div.search-instructions').hide();
        $('div.search-results').show('slow');
     });

}
```